# How to modify timestamp?

Tags: php, timestamp

Why it dosn't work with timestamp?

```
$date = date_create('@1409221272');
date_modify($date, '+1 day');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This works

```
$date = date_create('28-08-2014 13:20:00');
date_modify($date, '+1 day');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: If that works then what is your problem?

Comment: `$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(1409221272);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` should work..

Comment: To John Robertson - because i need timestamp based

Comment: And what prevents you from changing the date back to timestamp? By the way, I ran your first example and it works ok.

Comment: its from db. First example have hour issue

Comment: THANKS Abhik Chakraborty, your solution worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to create a DateTime object from a timestamp:

```
$date = date_create();
date_timestamp_set($date, 1171502725);
date_modify($date, '+1 day');
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php